# Calling variable from another classes method - Python (and PyQt)

Tags: python, sql, pyqt

I need a variable that holds login details, all my classes are in separate files.

The first class is the login window which will get the usernames and passwords from a database

```
        LoginBtn.clicked.connect(self.CheckLogin)

def CheckLogin(self):
    self.username = self.usernameLE.text()
    self.password = self.passwordLE.text()

    with sqlite3.connect("Accounts.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username=? ",(self.username,))
        self.account = cursor.fetchone()

    try:
        if self.account[0] == self.username and self.account[1] == self.password:
            if self.account[2] == 'Admin':
                self.OpenSystem = CurrentLayoutAdmin()
                self.OpenSystem.show()
                self.hide()
            elif self.account[2] == 'Manager':
                self.departmentsave = self.account[2]
                self.OpenManagerSystem = CurrentLayoutManager() #This goes to main menu and once a button is clicked it opens up another window. The one I need the variable for.
                self.OpenManagerSystem.show()
                self.hide()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            self.invalid_lbl.setVisible(True)
            self.passwordLE.setText('')               
    except TypeError:
        self.invalid_lbl.setVisible(True)
        self.passwordLE.setText('')
```

I need the `self.account[2]` which holds the department.

```
def CreateTable(self): 
    accountdetails = LoginWindow()
    accountdetails.CheckLogin()
    print(accountdetails.departmentsave)
```

I can't figure out how to call this variable.

Comment: Can you just add a class attribute, like this: `self.departmentsave = self.account[2]` within the method shown?

Comment: Sorry, I dont entirely understand what you mean (new to python). I have made that variable, but i dont understand how to call it from the other class

Comment: Ignore me, I stupidly was putting the class attribute in the brackets of the actual class not the __init__()

Comment: Well if you still need help, you would call it exactly as you have already. I'm not sure I understand the problem actually, but if you would do `self.departmentsave = self.account[2]` inside your CheckLogin method, then you can just do exactly this: `print(accountdetails.departmentsave)` and it would work. If I understand your question correctly I can put the above in an answer below.